# Почему не сохранятся localStorage после обновления/перехода на другие страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Хочу записывать время входа посетителя, чтобы в дальнейшем выводить это время в личном кабинете:

```js
var today = new Date(); // Эти данные будут записаны в localstorage
var user_login_btn = document.querySelector('.user_login_submit'); // user_login_submit - это кнопка, на которую вешается событие

if(user_login_btn != null){ //проверка на существование, т.к другие страницы ругаются
  document.querySelector('.user_login_submit').addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.localStorage.setItem('login_date', today);
    
  });
}
var user_login_date = window.localStorage.getItem('login_date');
  if(user_login_date){
    $('.user_login_date').text(user_login_date); //user_login_date - это блок, куда должна выводиться информация
  }else{
    $('.user_login_date').text('noData');
  }
```

При клике localstorage записывается, но после обновления слетает. Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Comment: Проверил, код работает. Если не обновляется значение в Chrome Developer Tools, то надо закрыть и открыть панель заново (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327117/how-to-update-google-chrome-developer-tools-local-storage-view) или посмотреть в Firefox.

Comment: @DmitryTaipov, в firefox тоже проверял, данные записываются, но после перехода  на другую страницу слетают, закрыть-открыть devtools пробовал, значения не сохранились

Comment: именно в localStorage значения не сохраняются или на странице не появляются в нужный момент? Может быть, попробовать упростить код, при загрузке страницы писать console.log(localStorage.getItem('login_date'));